# ¿Por que cuando corro un servicio de un CountDownTimer en el emulador funciona bien pero cuando lo corro en el móvil no funciona?

Tags: java, android

Codigo simple, pero como digo cuando corro el servicio en el emulador funciona bien sigue el contador en reversa, hasta cuando cierro la aplicacion sigue funcionando, pero cuando lo pruebo en el mobil funciona el servicio mientras esta la aplicacion en uso pero cuando cierro la aplicacion el servicio deja de funcionar alguien sabe a que se deba

```
 @Override
public int onStartCommand(@Nullable Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    new CountDownTimer(120000, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            Toast.makeText(MyServiceTwoMinutes.this, "seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            Toast.makeText(MyServiceTwoMinutes.this, "Acabado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }.start();
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido, agrega el còdigo como texto ya que no es visible. revisa [ask], saludos

Comment: Puede deberse a que el sistema operativo de tu móvil es inferior a lo especificado al crear el proyecto, le recomiendo que pruebe sus proyectos con una maquina virtual si lo hace con un dispositivo físico e al contrario para comprobar si el problema persiste, un saludo.

Answer (score 2):

Las apps orientadas a android 8 o superior tienen [limites de ejecucion en segundo plano](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes?hl=es-419#back-all), por lo que tu servicio solo funciona mientras la app se encuentre en primer plano. Para mantener funcionando tu servicio aunque la app no se encuentre en uso, inicialo en [foreground](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services#Foreground).

Asegurate de llamar a stopForeground una vez que tu servicio haya completado su trabajo.

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(@Nullable Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Notification notification =
      new Notification.Builder(this, CHANNEL_DEFAULT_IMPORTANCE)
        .setContentTitle(getText(R.string.notification_title))
        .setContentText(getText(R.string.notification_message))
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
        .build();
    //Corriendo el servicio en primer plano
    startForeground(ONGOING_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);

    new CountDownTimer(120000, 1000) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            Toast.makeText(MyServiceTwoMinutes.this, "seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            Toast.makeText(MyServiceTwoMinutes.this, "Acabado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    
            //Deteniendo el servicio
            stopForeground(true);
            stopSelf()
        }
    }.start();
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo que puede estar sucediendo es que en el dispositivo físico el SO detenga el servicio para liberar memoria RAM, a mi me pasaba lo mismo Programmer!, tanto en el emulador como en dispositivos físicos. Lo que puedes hacer es implementar un Broadcast que utilice el servicio de alarma del SO para mantener "vivo" el servicio en caso de que el SO lo detenga.

AlarmReceiver.java

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //Iniciar el servicio
        Intent background = new Intent(context, YourService.class);
        context.startService(background);
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="REFRESH_SERVICE" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Luego en la actividad principal instancias el Broadcast para que se ejecute cada x tiempo e inicie el servicio en caso de que el SO lo haya defendido
MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Iniciar el Broadcast para que no muera el proceso
        String alarm = Context.ALARM_SERVICE;
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(alarm);
        Intent intent = new Intent("REFRESH_SERVICE");
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 123456789, intent, 0);
        int type = AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP;
        //Intervalo de tiempo en millisegundos que se ejecutará onReceive en el BroadCast
        long interval = 60000;
        alarmManager.setRepeating(type, System.currentTimeMillis(), interval, pendingIntent);
    }
}
```

Es importante que no sobrecargues el servicio con mucho código porque puedes crear una mala experiencia de usuario. Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: ok gracias pero a qui el problema recide en que cuando cierro la app deja de funcionar el servicio no ase su funcion el START_STICKY de iniciar el servicio aun cerrando la app pero solo pasa en el dispositivo fisico por que al probarlo con un emulador funciona perfectamente. pero gracias este Broadcast me puede servir mas adelante