# Como hacer que WorkManager lance la alarma cuando la app este cerrada

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase

Me gustaría que WorkManager siguiera lanzando la notificación+alarma cuando la app esté cerrada. Por ahora solo me las lanza en primer y segundo plano.

Veo codigo para añadir al manifest..pero no se si será la solución o que. En lo que encuentro aparecen cosas que son con BroadcastReceiver, pero yo no puedo extender esto ya que con WorkManager extiendo la clase Worker...

Por otro lado no paro de encontrar hilos por aquí sobre FCM... pero no me gustaría tirar todo lo echo por implementarlo..

Que opción eligiríais vosotros? Gracias

Comment: Revisa esta pregunta Rubén y si aún tienes dudas nos pones el código nos a ver como podemos ayudarte. https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/369390/por-que-cuando-corro-un-servicio-de-un-countdowntimer-en-el-emulador-funciona-b/369426?noredirect=1#comment662841_369426

Comment: Gracias Ariel.. No sabría donde incluir ese método sobre todo cuando tenga que borrar el Foreground.. Al final el otro dia indagando por internet, me encontré que yendo al ahorro de la bateria del móvil, y permitiendo que siga corriendo aunque la cierre el usuario, me llegan las notificaciones aunque haya cerrado la app.

Comment: No sé, si esto es muy acertado, puesto que cualquier usuario que se descargue la app, no tiene porque ir a hacer cambios en sus ajustes del tlf para esa app, lo más cómodo es instalarlo y que todo esté echo por la app. Ando buscando a ver si hay alguna solucion como decía en mi pregunta.. Sino, ya me dirás Ariel como podría implementar la parte de eliminar la notificación Foreground, ya que mi app es un recordatorio, entonces hasta que no se elimine el recordatorio, éste ira recordando al usuario cada día o número de horas a través de una notificacion las cosas..